# How to change an element from string to float in a nested list

Tags: python, string

I want to use list comprehension to change an element within a nested list to float.

```
lines = [[1, '74.37000326528938', 'Psychologist'], [2, '67.49686206937491', 'Psychologist'], [3, '74.92356434760966', 'Psychologist']]
>>> lines = [[line[0]] + [float(x) for x in line[1]] + [line[2]] for line in lines]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: .
```

I also don't understand why this would work for a different example:

```
mylist = [['1','2','3'],['5','6','7']]
datl3 = [[int(x) for x in line[0]] + line[1:] for line in mylist]
datl4 = [[line[0]] + [float(x) for x in line[1]] + [line[2]] for line in datl3]
>>> datl4
[[1, 2.0, '3'], [5, 6.0, '7']]
```

I think it has to do with decimal points, because the code won't work for this example:

```
mylist = [['1','2.555','3'],['5','6.777','7']]
datl3 = [[int(x) for x in line[0]] + line[1:] for line in mylist]
datl4 = [[line[0]] + [float(x) for x in line[1]] + [line[2]] for line in datl3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: .
```

Comment: Why are you building a new list? Shouldn't `for l in lines: l[1] = float(l[1])` work?

Comment: @coldspeed Would the for loop only change the element l[1]?

Comment: No, since `l` is a reference to an inner list, it ends up modifying the original `lines`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close but the problem was that you were using a `for` loop on `line[1]` which is a single string. Hence, you were looping through each element/character of your float number. When you reach the decimal `.` you get the `ValueError: could not convert string to float: .`. Your second example works because there you just have a single digit strings `2` and `6` without any decimal.

If you stick to your code, you just need to replace the index `line[1]` by `line[1:2]` as follows where you slice

```
lines = [[line[0]] + [float(x) for x in line[1:2]] + [line[2]] for line in lines]
```

However, a more concise way is following where you avoid an unnecessary intermediary for loop by directly accessing the second element of the sublists. You don't need to create three sublists and then add them using `+`

```
lines = [[line[0], float(line[1]), line[2]] for line in lines]
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 74.37000326528938, 'Psychologist'],
 [2, 67.49686206937491, 'Psychologist'],
 [3, 74.92356434760966, 'Psychologist']]
```

Comment: `for x in line[1:2]` is a complicated way of getting `line[1]`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: I agree but my aim here was to tell the OP what is going wrong in his/her approach. Reading all three answers, I feel we all are telling the same thing about the decimal

Comment: You could add to your question by showing how to write the final solution in a more clear and concise way.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this line is trying to do too many things at once:

```
datl4 = [[line[0]] + [float(x) for x in line[1]] + [line[2]] for line in datl3]
```

The problem occurs in the inner list comprehension:

```
[float(x) for x in line[1]]
```

But what is `line[1]`? It comes from the iteration `for line in datl3`. So let's see what values it has:

```
>>> [line[1] for line in datl3]
['2.555', '6.777']
```

So when you do `[float(x) for x in line[1]]` you are iterating over the characters of each numerical string...`"2"` then `"."` then `"5"` then `"5"` then `"5"`. But `"."` is not a valid float.

I think what you want to do instead is just convert `line[1]` to a `float`:

```
lines = [[line[0], float(line[1]), line[2]] for line in lines]
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with *list comprehension* just need to set it up properly, check the `str` for a decimal, if so make that item an `int`

```
l = [[float(j) if '.' in str(j) else j for j in i] for i in l]
```

> ```
> [[1, 74.37000326528938, 'Psychologist'], [2, 67.49686206937491, 'Psychologist'], [3, 74.92356434760966, 'Psychologist']]
> ```